# Why am I getting a NPE on my base Realm instance?

Tags: android, realm

I am experiencing a NPE for about 1% of my users but I am unable to reproduce the crash. I have a base activity that has an instance of realm, that I access throughout my other activities / fragments. In one fragment, during a transaction, I am getting a NPE on that base instance. Why is this happening, and only to some users?

**Base Activity**

```
public Realm realm;

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    }

@Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (realm != null) {
            realm.removeAllChangeListeners();
            realm.close();
        }

        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

**Base Fragment**

```
protected Realm getRealm() {
        if (getActivity() != null && getActivity() instanceof BaseActivity) {
            return ((BaseActivity)getActivity()).realm;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

**MyErrorFragment**

```
private MyClass myInstance;

protected void myErrorMethod() {
        getRealm().executeTransactionAsync(realm -> realm.createObject(ExerciseOptionsResult.class, optionsKey), () -> {
                    myInstance = getRealm()
                            .where(ExerciseOptionsResult.class) // THIS IS WHERE I GET A NPE
                            .equalTo("optionsKey", optionsKey)
                            .findFirst();
                    applyChangeListenerToItem();
                });
            } else {
                doSomethingElse(myInstance);
            }
        }

        initView();
        initOtherView();
    }
```

Comment: *Why is this happening* because fragments can be in a state where they are not attached to an activity. Then getRealm will return null and boom crash

Comment: `getActivity()` was null, I guess -- the stack trace would have helped